# How do I cut mesh partially with EzySlice?

Tags: unity, 2d, mesh, vertex

I'm using the EzySlice framework to cut meshes (https://github.com/DavidArayan/ezy-slice).

[image]

So far it can cut a mesh but infinitely but I want to be able to cut partially like this:
[image]

As you see in the 3rd photo, only 1 vertex is created at the end of the dotted line away from the outer edge. However the rest of the vertices created by the cut are in pairs. How do I achieve this effect?

Comment: What do you have as inputs? Do you already know the specific triangle you want to cut into, the starting point/edge, the direction and depth of the cut? Or do these need to be determined from some other input? Is the notch always contained inside a single triangle as shown here, or do you need to be able to slice across edges other than the perimeter edge?

Comment: And that's sufficient if you want to cut all the way through. But what you want is to cut part-way, from one side. So we need at least two more parameters: which side to cut from, and how deep to cut. How would you like to describe this partial cut, in terms of the input you provide to the cutting method? We'll also still need an answer to the question above about whether the notch is allowed to cross an internal edge.