# How do I distinguish if parts of a mesh are together or separate/disconnected?

Tags: unity, mesh

Let's say I have a GameObject that has a MeshFilter with this mesh data.

[image]

These shapes are generated at runtime and all considered 1 mesh under the MeshFilter. What I want to do is separate the two, store them in a mesh array, and then create individual GameObject for both of them with their own MeshFilter and MeshRenderer. How do I distinguish that the square circled in red is unique from the shape on the left?

Comment: How do you generate these shapes at runtime? What's the process to create the geometry, and what does the geometry look like (eg. show us the triangles. Are there vertices shared between  different elements?)

Comment: From that gif, it looks like you found an answer to [your earlier question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/197573/how-do-i-cut-mesh-partially-with-ezyslice)? Want to post that solution as an Answer there? To answer your new question, we'll need to know whether your cutting method produces shared vertices along the parts of the cut that remain in contact, or two separate vertices that happen to coincide at the same position.

Comment: Those are great details to include in your question, so they're not hidden in a comment. Be sure to embed the images so they're visible without clicking an external link.